# Try to call the vuex getter in watch

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter, watch

I'm trying to call a Vuex getter in the component watch.
But it tells me that it is undefined what is not.
So i try to return the getter in the computed object but still doesn t work.

```
        name: "FreeTalk",
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getCharacter','getResultStatus', 'getFreeTalkText', 'getResult', 'freeTalkResult', 'getFreeTalkNoNative', 'getFreeTalkMedium','getFreeTalkNative']),
            progressStatus() {
                return this.getResult.progress
            },
            getStatus() {
                return this.getResultStatus
            }
        },
        watch: {
            progressStatus: (val) => {
                if (val == 100) {
                    this.status = this.getStatus()
                    if (this.getStatus === 0) {
                        this.outputText = this.getFreeTalkNoNative.result;
                    } else if (this.getStatus === 1) {
                        this.outputText = this.getFreeTalkMedium;
                    } else if (this.getStatus === 2) {
                        this.outputText = this.getFreeTalkNative;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                outputText: '',
                ready: false,
                isRecordDone: false,
                status: -1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain the context of your task, what is actually happening? Potentially the data in the store is not yet loaded and then the watcher is going to return errors if it's using the values from the store before it has data.

Comment: Does the `getResult` getter transform the data from the store, so ...mapState is therefore not an option instead of ...mapGetters?

Comment: You have to define your getStatus methods in the "methods:" section. Then you can call it from your watcher.